# deprecated conversion from string to char *

Tags: c, string, char, nvcc

I want to get a filename from the command line or set a default name for that. So, previously I used

```
static char *fName;
if (argc == 2 ) {
    fName = argv[1];
}
else {
    fName = "default_file.txt";
}
```

But for the `else`, I get `warning: conversion from a string literal to "char *" is deprecated`. If I try something like this:

```
static char fName [30] = "default_file.txt";
if (argc == 2 ) {
    fName = argv[1]; //error
}
```

Now, I get `error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue`. So, how can I fix that?

Comment: The problem for the first is that you're using a **C++** compiler, or something as silly.

Comment: This seems like a c++ warning. The second one is because arrays are not lvalues and you cannot assign to them.

Comment: Otherwise the first one is quite OK C, though I don't get why `fName` is defined as *static*...

Comment: Well, actually I am using `nvcc` fom cuda-7.5 for a `.cu` file. As for the static definition, that is the code and not necessary. I can remove it!

Comment: `static char *fName;` --> `static const char *fName;`

Comment: If `fName` is a global variable, then `static` is probably the better option, if it's a local variable, then `static` should probably  not be used.

Comment: You can't copy array with `=`

Comment: cuda-C is misnamed.  It is C++, and nvcc is a C++ compiler.  (At least, it was 4 years ago.  I suspect it hasn't changed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> warning: conversion from a string literal to "char *" is deprecated

This almost certainly means that you are using a C++ compiler. String literals (like `"default_file.txt"` in your example) was once of type `char[]` in C and C++ both. Writing to a string literal invokes undefined behavior. Because of this, C++ changed the type of string literals to `const char[]`. But in C, the type remains `char[]`. The warning is therefore an indication that you are using a C++ compiler for compiling C code, which is often not wise.

Note that it is however bad practice in C as well as C++, to have a non-`const`-qualified pointer to a string literal.

---

> Now, I get error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

Because you can't assign a value to an array in run-time using assignment operators. The C syntax does not allow this. You would have to use memcpy, strcpy or similar.

---

Corrected code should be something like this:

```
static const char* fName = "default_file.txt";

if (argc == 2 ) {
   fName = argv[1];
}
```

This is fine for C and C++ both, though in C++ it is recommended practice to use `std::string` instead.